# how to follow statuses of a list of users using twitter streaming api in node.js with twit module

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am using twit node.js module for twitter api, I am trying to get status stream of a list of users by using their id but when i run the script it the following error

```
Error: Bad Twitter streaming request: 406
```

Following is the code

```
var http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, Twit = require('twit')
server.listen(4040);

var T = new Twit({
consumer_key:           'abc'
, consumer_secret:      'abc'
, access_token:         'abc'
, access_token_secret:  'abc'
});
var watchList = ['@Kashmala_Tariq', '@Mushahid', '@Fbuttho'];
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow : watchList });

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
console.log('@'+tweet.user.screen_name + ':::' + tweet.text);
});
```

this is the link to the api i am using 
[twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)[twit-module](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)

please guide me what is it that i am doing wrong in this script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can to use the id instead of the screen_name:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow : ['123456789', '23456789'] });
stream.on('tweet', function (tweet, err) {
    console.log(tweet);
})
```

Moreover, you can figure out the id by using a service like http://gettwitterid.com.

Comment: Using about method, I have received retweet also. How to avoid it. or I have to ignore from my side.